# How can I convert a String into a DataInputStream type in Java?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, inputstream, datainputstream

Is there any way to do this conversion in Java? I have tried the suggested tips online for converting a String into an InputStream type, but it is not the same, and there is nothing else online that I can find.

Comment: Needs code.  What have you tried?  Also please show what output and input you expect, sometimes just "string" doesn't really tell us anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("hi I am test".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(is);
        while (dataIn.available() > 0) {
            String k = dataIn.readLine();
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you to convert `String` into `DataInputStream`

```
String string = "Sample String";
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
```